# Filter function for Array of Objects

Tags: reactjs, typescript, filter

I'm following this tutorial and made a few changes to typescript for learning purposes but got stuck when creating a filter function from react context script.

I have a working function called getCampaigns where it maps all the object from the blockchain like below:

```
 const getCampaigns = useCallback(async () => {
    const signer = accountProvider?.getSigner();
    const contractWithSigner = contract?.connect(signer);
    const campaigns = await contractWithSigner?.getCampaigns();
    const parsedCampaigns = campaigns.map((campaign, i) => ({
      owner: campaign.owner,
      title: campaign.title,
      description: campaign.description,
      target: ethers.utils.formatEther(campaign.target.toString()),
      deadline: campaign.deadline.toNumber(),
      amountCollected: ethers.utils.formatEther(
        campaign.amountCollected.toString()
      ),
      image: campaign.image,
      pId: i,
    }));

    return parsedCampaigns;
  }, [contract, accountProvider]);
```

This is working as it should and manage to see the content like below:

```
[{…}]
0: 
amountCollected:"0.0"
deadline:1673049600000
description: "I want to build a Robot"
image:"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAA
owner:"0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266"
pId:0
target:"3.0"
title:"Build a Robot"
```

As my new function, I wanted to filter from the getCampaigns function only to display all of the owner's post and display it on a Profile page like below:

```
  const getUserCampaigns = async () => {
    const allCampaigns = await getCampaigns();

    const filteredCampaigns = allCampaigns.filter(
      campaign => campaign.owner === account
    );

    

    return filteredCampaigns;
  };
```

So when I console.log filteredCampaigns, it doesnt show any result. Is there anything that I missed here? The typeof account is string and it is working if I put it like this

```
const filteredCampaigns = allCampaigns.filter(
      campaign => campaign.owner === "0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266"
    );
```

Update:

So far I have been playing around with the syntax and console.log the following:

```
 const filteredCampaigns = allCampaigns.filter(campaign => {
      console.log(campaign.owner);
      return campaign.owner === account;
    });
```

it's managed to fetch the same data and the typeof campaign.owner is in fact a string (same as typeof account). But when I run it like this

```
const filteredCampaigns = allCampaigns.filter(campaign => {
      console.log(campaign.owner === account.toString());
      return campaign.owner === account;
    });
```

It's still come out as false

It is working if I hard coded like this

```
console.log(campaign.owner === "0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266")
```

Comment: Where is `account` defined?

Comment: its imported from another context file const { account, accountProvider } = useAccount();

Comment: Are you sure the import is working and that `account` isn't null? Did you try printing out the value of `account`?

Comment: yup the account isn't null . I have console.log it and it returns the same address and the typeof is string

Answer (score 0):

`filteredCampaign` is empty, because the content of account doesn't match any content of `campaign.owner`.

Check the content of `account`.

```
allCampaign.filter(elementOfArray => condition)
```

return element only if condition is true.
The logic of your getUserCampaign, looks right for what you want to do.

Not sure if this is the case, but may have sense, to have a field/global var/state where you keep all your campaigns.
In this way when you want to filter, you can do something like

```
const filteredCampaign = (account: string) => {
  return allCampaigns.filter(campaign => campaign.owner === account);
}
```

filteredCampaign is not anymore async call, because doesn't have to await and receive the
`account`